# Normal vector and Cartesian product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Given a vector $\vec{v} = [v_1,v_2,v_3]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and a circle $\vec{c} = [r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta,1]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^3$, how to express the normal vector of the polytope constructed as $\vec{p} = (\vec{c},\vec{v}\times \vec{c})\in \mathbb{R}^6$ (the Cartesian product of the circle and its cross product with the vector $\vec{v}$)?

Comment: Just differentiate the unit tangent vector, no?

Comment: @user10354138 I guess you're right. Thanks!